# Querying All_Subscribers view

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a custom attribute called 'CustomerID' in my All Subscribers list. I want to query All Subscribers on this field. Is there a way I can do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an Enterprise 2.0 account, then you can query the `_EnterpriseAttribute` [System Data View](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) to retrieve the value of `CustomerID`.

If not, then you'll have to do a Tracking Extract of Attributes and import it back into a Data Extension.

Comment: Thanks Adam! Can you please give me an example query using this view? The documentation says that this view has just one field (_SubscriberId) .. How do I access the CustomerId attribute?

Comment: You'll need to join from the _Subscribers data view using the SubscriberID: https://gist.github.com/wvpv/f9afc474ad3e3ae316cd